# How to use percentage score for significant terms aggregations in Nest

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm trying to recreate the following aggregation in Nest

```
"aggs": {
    "related_organisations": {
        "significant_terms": {
             "field": "organisations.keyword",
                 "percentage": {},
                 "min_doc_count": 5
                 "size": 10
             }
         }
     }
}
```

I can't figure out what's meant to go in the function expression for `PercentageScore`

```
.Aggregations(a => a
    .SignificantTerms("related_organisations", sigTerms => sigTerms
        .Field("organisations.keyword")
        .Size(10)
        .PercentageScore(p => [[what goes here??]])
        .MinimumDocumentCount(5)
```

I can get it to compile by just doing `p => p` but it doesn't build the query correctly and throws an exception

```
System.TypeLoadException: GenericArguments[0], 'Nest.PercentageScoreHeuristic', on 'Nest.ReadAsFormatter`2[TRead,T]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TRead'.
```

I have also tried `null` and `new PercentageScoreHeuristicDescriptor()` with no luck.

Comment: I think worth reporting [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues).

Comment: opened https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/4573

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this is a bug, and a fix is being worked on.

For solving this problem until I am able to use the fixed version of Nest, I have used the script score, and replicated the percentage score within it:

```
.Aggregations(a => a
    .SignificantTerms("related_organisations", sigTerms => sigTerms
        .Field("organisations.keyword")
        .Size(10)
        .Script(s => s.Script("params._subset_freq/params._superset_freq"))
        .MinimumDocumentCount(5)
```